# How to delete or remove array data from document i n mongodb using php

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, collections, document

Here are the JSON i want to delete { points: 55, bonus: 20 } from points

```
{
       _id: 3,
       name: "ahn",
       age: 22,
       type: 2,
       status: "A",
       favorites: { artist: "Cassatt", food: "cake" },
       finished: [ 6 ],
       badges: [ "blue", "red" ],
       points: [
          { points: 81, bonus: 8 },
          { points: 55, bonus: 20 },
          { points: 56, bonus: 25 }
       ]
}
```

I want to see this result

```
{
       _id: 3,
       name: "ahn",
       age: 22,
       type: 2,
       status: "A",
       favorites: { artist: "Cassatt", food: "cake" },
       finished: [ 6 ],
       badges: [ "blue", "red" ],
       points: [
          { points: 81, bonus: 8 },
          { points: 56, bonus: 25 }
       ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $pull of MongoDB

```
    db.collection.update(
      { },
      { $pull: { points:  { points: 55, bonus: 20 } } },
    )
```

*{multi: true}: adding this in above query will delete all entries matching { points: 55, bonus: 20 }*

Answer (score 0):

```
collection->update(array("_id"=>$document["_id"]),array('$pull'=>array("points"=>array("points"=>55,"bonus"=>20)));
```

In PHP using this code to remove documents from document